# create a reslover and graphql query for city and area

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

[image]

**my current resolver is**
[image]

my current graphql schema is
[image]

Iam looking for a graphql schema and resolver that if i select a city
then all the area will display
can you give me graphql query also and  what changes must do on the code

Comment: add code above class
 
use vendor\modulename\Model\ResourceModel\modulename\DeliveryCityCollectionFactory;

use vendor\modulename\Model\DeliveryCityCollectionFactory;

apply Magento deploy commands.

Please try to check it.